# How I can return multi response

Tags: http, go, httpresponse

I've read about asynchronous response and,
I am trying to return multi response using golang, 
but I don't know how I can do that.

my example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", multiResponse)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func multiResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go func() {
        resp, err := http.Get("https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=hello")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        // w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        // w.Write(body)
        fmt.Fprintln(w, string(body))

        resp.Body.Close()

        fmt.Println("done...")
    }()

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)
}
```

is there any examples to understand asynchronous response?

**Edit:**
I meaning about multiple response,
when I receive request from client I will send [StatusAccepted](https://httpstatuses.com/202) immediately, 
and in another goroutine other process work, then after finishing send [StatusOK](https://httpstatuses.com/200) with some data.

Comment: What you mean by multiple response in HTTP response? Is it chunked/incremental response write you're referring?

Comment: The http/server completes the response when the handler returns.  You need to add a wait group or some other synchronization to block the handler until the goroutine completes.  A simpler approach is to eliminate the goroutine and execute all code in the hander's goroutine.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: You might want to look into go channels for async responses.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? 
HTTP/1.x generally is single request -> single response.
You might look at WebSocket instead, or even HTTP/2.0 Server Push.